# How to reference Form in submit button for file uploads

Tags: google-apps-script

In https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication the example indicates that you should reference the form by 'this.parent' in the button onclick. How best should the form be referenced if the button is not directly under the form (perhaps several divs deep? this.parentNode.parentNode and so on works but a more explicit reference would suit me better.

```html
<form id="myForm">
    <input name="myFile" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Submit"
        onclick="google.script.run
          .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
          .processForm(this.parentNode)" />
</form>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: Why don't you use document.getElementById() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that in your case may be using:

```
onclick="google.script.run
      .withSuccessHandler(updateUrl)
      .processForm(document.getElementById('formId')"
```